# joomla vs concrete5 for database driven site

Tags: joomla, concrete5

I have to build a administration site for my association, and I was in doubt between choosing joomla or concrete 5 for it.

In the specific I need to have administrators that can watch the data and users who must be able to modify database data. The data of course is user specific.

Which solution could be better for my needs?

Answer (score 2):

Does this site *only* handle this data task? Or is it a "normal" website with lots of content, and this data function is only one part of that?

If the website isn't primarily page- and content-focused, then you don't want to use a CMS at all -- you'd be better served by one of the frameworks (in php, try CodeIgniter, or if you're a more advanced programmer try Symfony or Kohana).

But if you do have a website that has lots of pages and content, and this data function is only one part of it, well then it really depends on what you're familiar with already. Are you currently experienced in either Joomla or Concrete5? If so, stick with what you know (unless you're looking for an excuse to learn a new system, in which case by all means use the one you don't know). I personally think Concrete5 is vastly superior to work with, both because it "stays out of your way" as a developer and lets you code your custom functionality up any way you want (check out the "single_page" functionality, which is what you'd want for this project), and also because it provides a much more intuitive editing interface for the users of the site. Concrete5 is one of the newer php CMS's, so I believe it has the benefit of "learning from the mistakes" of earlier systems like Joomla, Drupal, etc. But on the other hand, because the older systems (like Joomla) have been around longer, there is a lot more documentation, books, forums, etc. available.

Best of luck.

Comment: it's the problem with every new cms: innovation against support. I agree that concrete looks sexy, while joomla attract me with it's comprehensive framework. the reason i was thinking about using a cms is because also administrators (aka computer idiots) has to add some content such as files, calendars event, forms etc...

Comment: In that case, definitely concrete5. It by far has the best interface for computer idiots to work with.